# run a url in django backend

Tags: python, django

I need the server to open a url in the backend, before returning an http response, any http response.

For example, After user enters his/her phone number and submits, in my views, a url like:

> example.com/api/publicapi/ptpsms?username=username&password=password ...

is ran, and then a page is renderd, asking user to enter the code that was sent to him/her by sms.

Comment: maybe you should look at how to handle GET/POST requests and how django views works with urls

Comment: I know what you just said, but I'm looking for a way to run a url, out of my website's urls, and then redirect to a page inside my website

Comment: see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: What does "run a URL" mean? What is calling this URL? Where from? How is this different from any other request?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - For full disclosure, the op had [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/fc711ff0-1035-4a55-9617-32ea847dc4e3/view-source) their question to indicate that the request library solved their problem.. I removed it since the answer isn't part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

This one did the Job, thanks to Vipul

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to make a request to an external service through a http request inside your view.
You might want to look for a http client https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html
Then get the response and do whatever you need to do inside your view before returning it to your client.